# Calls to WebProxy without an app context are not allowed

Tags: javascript, rest, client-object-model

From SharePoint 2013's default.aspx page (https://somecompany-public.sharepoint.com/pages/default.aspx) I'm trying to call a RESTful json API which lives outside the SharePoint domain, but getting error:

> Calls to WebProxy without an app context are not allowed.

There is no app involved here - I'm putting the following JavaScript right inside the default.aspx using script editor:

```
<script language="javascript">

var responseDocument = undefined;

function onSuccess() {
    var response = responseDocument.get_body();
    alert('success ' + response);//this line gives the error in my question
}

function onError(err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
}

$(function () {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
    request.set_url('https://api.somedomain.com/data/10001');
    request.set_method("GET");
    responseDocument = SP.WebProxy.invoke(ctx, request); // executes on sp server
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onError);
});

</script>
```

**EDIT Jan 15, 2015 2:30 PM**
Is it not possible to get a `ClientContext` object of the root domain? Something like the `siteCollection` or `website` object below (code modified from [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245759%28v=office.15%29.aspx))

```
// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();
    siteCollection = clientContext.get_site();
    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.load(siteCollection);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find an alternative way to make your cross domain calls. As stated by the error, you cannot use the WebProxy if you're not inside an App.

The App context is needed to tell the WebProxy that the URL being queried has been approved (it's part of the App manifest)

Try creating a SharePoint Hosted app for the feature you are building and following [this tutorial to configure the remote endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: You can set authorized 'remote endpoints' inside of a SharePoint app and make cross domain calls using the web proxy. Here is a walkthrough on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Kindly see my edit

Comment: If it belongs to the same domain (everything before the first / is the same [ignoring http://]) you shouldn't run in to any cross domain issues. A variation of the code you posted, with the URL as a parameter is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245896(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @Choggo The API is a whole different domain. And I'm trying to find out why a ClientContext cannot be created of the root domain. They surely allow for a Sharepoint app domain, then why not root domain? *Both* sit on *their* servers -  I don't understand if this is a security issue.

Comment: The problem is that it's a browser restriction (although, I guess they could work around it by sending in the response headers the acceptable URLs for cross domain queries) the browser itself blocks the requests and not SharePoint. Mind you, someone might know a workaround or how to guide you better then me in this.

Comment: Added WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp to my API so now I can use jsonP without any issues. No need to SP.js - useless, unfortunately.

Comment: @greatbear302 It's not really useless at all; you just decided not to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @John-M well not useless, i admit. But it was complicating things more than they needed to be - in my case at least. jQuery supports jsonP for a long time and simply works!